# VerticalIntensityStatistics similar in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, aforge

I'm developing a C++ project which requires to calculate the Vertical Intensity histogram of a given image. The input image I have and the output I'm looking to get, is similar to this: [image]

I don't know which OpenCV function fits best to get the output I need. 
I've tried with `calcHist` function and the `reduce` function but both of them seem not to work due to my fault in passing args.

Considering that I have got a good B&W image, could someone help me to calculate the histogram?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opencv has a builtin function for that: [reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce)

(calcHist won't work, because it bins intensities, not projected pixel counts)

```
reduce(img,0,CV_REDUCE_SUM); // horizontal
reduce(img,1,CV_REDUCE_SUM); // vertical
```

(hehe, images from a code-proj. article ? remember that one ...)

Comment: Ok, that worked. Thank you very much Berak. Yeah, that's a good article :).

In order to obtain and use the histogram I defined:
MatND hist_y;
reduce(img, hist_y, 1, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_32FC1);

Comment: you don't need a MatND, an ordinary Mat will do (actually they're the same)